# how to use string.format.. and can we add a character with integer and store it in integer like in below code

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

CODE :

```
public class Theatre {
    
    private final String theatreName;
    private List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Theatre(String thName, int numRows, int seatsPerRow) {
        this.theatreName = thName;
        
        int lastRow = 'A'+ (numRows-1);
        for(char s='A'; s<=lastRow; s++) {
            for(int seatNum=1; seatNum<=seatsPerRow; seatNum++) {
                Seat seat = new Seat(s + String.format("%02d", seatNum));
                seats.add(seat);
            }   
        }   
    }
```

pls explain me this part the working of for loop here using character i've never used a loop with char :

```
    int lastRow = 'A'+ (numRows-1);
    for(char s='A'; s<=lastRow; s++) {
        for(int seatNum=1; seatNum<=seatsPerRow; seatNum++) {
            Seat seat = new Seat(s + String.format("%02d", seatNum));
            seats.add(seat);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. In the title, you have already two question , 1. “how to use string.format” — way too broad, 2. ) “can we add a character with integer and store it in integer like in below code” — Obviously, we can. You have posted the code yourself. In the question text itself, you wrote “explain me this part the working of for loop” which is not a question. Asking a concrete question will clarify, what you didn’t understand about the code.

Answer (score 1):

Look at an [ASCII Chart](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html).

The integer value for the letter "A" is 65.

So essentially the loop keeps adding 1 to 65 to get then next character which would be "B", then "C" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, operations between `char` and `int` give an int result; char treated as unsigned 16 bit int. This is true for `short` and `int` too.

The `char <= int` will be an int comparison. In fact the jvm bytecode instruction `if_icmple` (*if int compare less-equal*) would typically be used,
even if *both* sides were byte, char or short.

```
        Seat seat = new Seat(((char)s) + String.format("%02d", seatNum));
        Seat seat = new Seat(String.format("%c%02d", s, seatNum));
```

%c taking a char, but accepts an int too.

Casting the result of char+int to char will give a new char as **@camickr** explained. The reason is that a char is UTF-16 encoded for Unicode. And there 'A' + 2 == 'C'. Note that some languages have different alphabets than 26 latin letters. Should you internationalize the program for Cyrillic this will become even more evident.

Comment: @Holger did not want to include camickr's answer; but still give the missing format asked. Maybe a comment should have sufficed.

Comment: Not only the `<=` operation will be an int operation. The initial assignment `s='A'` and also the `++` operation will also be done using `int` operations. The only difference is that after performing `++`, a conversion step will be done, to ensure that `\uFFFF` would overflow to `0` instead of yielding `0x10000`. That’s basically what a cast to `char` does, too. Since, as you said, the `%c` also accepts an `int`, the whole code would be slightly more efficient when declaring `s` as `int` and omitting all conversions.

Answer (score 0):

A char type can hold an integer which represents the ASCII value of the character.
So in:

```
int lastRow = 'A'+ (numRows-1);
```

`'A'` is equal to 65 and so if `numRows` is 10, `lastRow` is 74=`'J'`.

```
for(char s='A'; s<=lastRow; s++) {
```

variable `s` will loop over latin characters `A` through `J`. Since char and integer are exchangeable, you can do `s++` to move to the next character in the alphabet. You can walk through the whole ASCII table this way but it wouldn't make any sense in your theatre row context.